# How large can 6 equal squares be on 11x17 paper?

Tags: layout

Mathematically challenged here... I’d like to print 6 equal-size square images on an 11x17 page. The square images will then be cut from the page. Could someone tell me how large the squares can be if I want the printer to make the minimal number of cuts?

Many thanks for any help,

Robin

Answer (score 1):

11" / 2 = 5.5 " & 17" / 5.5 = ≈ 3.09
**∴ 5.5 <sup>2</sup> "**

So we conclude that 5.5" on a side squares should work fine - ***but*** it depends also upon the printable area of the sheet, which is printer-specific and you'll need to get effective area from your printer.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, Gerard! This is extremely helpful.